# Complex Conditional sort group by item containing others

Tags: linq

How to group list items by their parent's number. Relationship between parent and children is that children's numbers start with parent's number. Then I want to order by descending if item length is great than 2 then by ascending if length is 2.

Here is an Example:

[image: group by]

```
  var ordered=balances.GroupBy(item=>item.Num.StartsWith(???))
```

Couldn't try more possibilities because I don't know where to start

Comment: How do you know to group by "1" and "a"? In other words: what determines what part of the id is the parent's number?

Comment: Richard: If I am reading correctly because "12" exists and "121" starts with "12" then "12" is parent of "121". I assume 1 is not a parent of "12" because "1" doesn't exist. Likewise I assume "121" is parent of "1212" and "121c".

Comment: That's what I thought, but that doesn't match the example which puts "121" with "121c".

Comment: @Richard in this case 12 is parent of 121 while 121 is parent of 121c! saw?

Comment: But that is not what you have in the question! Are you saying, for those starting with "12", you should have three groups (12), (121) and (121c, 1212)?

Comment: Can you clarify why 1311 is before 132? I assume we must be ordering alphabetically (since they are not all numbers) but that would suggest if we are ordering descending that 132 should come before 1311. I have a solution but it gets those two the wrong way round...

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that does mostly what you want and can be modified to get your exact result. I didn't quite understand the ordering requirements so couldn't get code to match your exact example.

```
var inputs = new string[] {"12","121c","13","131","1311","ab","121","132","1212","abc"};

var roots = inputs.Where(x=>!inputs.Any(y=>x.StartsWith(y) && y!=x)).OrderBy(x=>x);
var grouped = roots.Select(x=>inputs.Where(y=>y.StartsWith(x)).OrderByDescending (y => y));
var finalList = grouped.SelectMany (x => x);
foreach(var item in finalList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The way this works is to first of all get our "roots" which is the ultimate parents. It does this by looping through all of the items. For each item (`x`) it then loops through again checking if `x` starts with any of the items apart from itself. If there are any then it is not a root parent (since that item is its parent).

This then gets us the items we want to group on. We then loop over these items getting any of the items that are children (or children of children, etc.) and sorting them. We then have a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`. We then use `SelectMany` to flatten this into our final list.

Currently the above outputs:

```
121c
1212
121
12
132
1311
131
13
abc
ab
```

Which has 132 before 1311. This is because under string ordering and descending 132 comes before 1311. To get this in the order you want you just need to update the OrderByDescending in the `grouped` line to implement the ordering you want.

This isn't a nice single line linq thing and it isn't necessarily efficient (the first part to get Roots is O(n^2)).